# Are any knot volumes known to be (ir)rational? If not, then why is the question difficult?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, knot-theory, knot-invariants

I'm reading C.C. Adams' *The Knot Book* (1994), and I'm intrigued by this assertion about the [hyperbolic volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_volume) of hyperbolic knots:

> Unsolved Question 2
>
> Is any one of the volumes a rational number $a/b$, where $a$ and $b$ are
> integers? Is any one of the volumes an irrational number (not of the
> form $a/b$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers)? Amazingly enough, even
> though we can calculate the volume of a knot out to as many decimal
> places as we want, we cannot tell whether any one of the volumes is
> either rational or irrational.

Some of the assertions in this edition feel a bit dated, so I wanted to ask whether this assertion is still current. Is there still no knot whose complement's volume has been determined to be either rational or irrational? If there is, then which knot is it, and is it in $\mathbb Q$ or not? If we still don't know, are there clear reasons for why the question is hard?

Comment: It is hard to find exact values in general, and unknown whether there are hyperbolic manifolds with rational volume at all. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548208/volumes-of-hyperbolic-manifolds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked Adams at a talk earlier this year if it's still true that we don't know the (exact) hyperbolic volume of a single knot. His answer was *yes."  --Ken Perko

Comment: @Leucippus I'm no knot theorist but it looks like an answer to the first question("is it still current") to me, relayed from the author of the book.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Adams doesn't know everything. --Ken Perko, lbrtpl@gmail.com.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, [the Wikipedia page on pretzel links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretzel_link) states that

> The hyperbolic volume of the complement of the (−2,3,8) pretzel link is 4 times [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant),

which is itself described as

> arguably the most basic constant whose irrationality and transcendence (though strongly suspected) remain unproven.

The [Whitehead link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_link) also has this complement volume.

Comment: Two examples are slim evidence on which to base a conjecture. --Ken Perko, lbrtpl@gmail.com